# How can I ensure that a "bind" filesystem is mounted after its parent filesystem?

Tags: mount, upstart, ubuntu-11.10

I have recently added a couple of entries to my fstab to allow me to rebind some directories to elsewhere in my filesystem tree, like this

```
/mnt/smb/foo/bar /home/mishagale/sourcecode/bar bind defaults,bind 0 0
```

However, /mnt/smb/foo happens to be an SMB filesystem (on a Samba server), with a line earlier in fstab that looks like

```
//192.168.1.7/foo/ /mnt/smb/foo smbfs uid=1000,gid=1000,rw,auto,user,user=myuser,pass=mypass 0 0
```

(obviously, these lines have been anonymised)

The problem is, now I get an error at boot time "`The disc drive for /home/mishagale/sourcecode/bar is not ready yet or not present`." If I skip mounting by hitting `S`, the system boots fine, but I then have to manually mount the offending mountpoint.

Is there a way I can instruct Ubuntu not to attempt to mount `bar` until `foo` has been successfully mounted? I believe this should be possible with upstart, but I'm not certain how to go about that.

I could (and will for now) just put the `noauto` option on `bar` and set a script that mounts them to run later, but this seems like a kludge to me, and I'm interested in learning the "proper" way to do it with Upstart.

```
$ cat /etc/lsb-release ; uname -a
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=11.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=oneiric
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 11.10"
Linux myhostname 3.0.0-14-generic #23-Ubuntu SMP Mon Nov 21 20:28:43 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you would implement this with 'automount' so that if the directory isn't in use it would automatically be unmounted, but as soon as you 'cd' to it, it'd mount and stay active as long as it's being used.

Incidentally, if you can use NFS instead of SMB, I would strongly suggest it. SMB is a really unfriendly and doesn't handle disconnects very well.

For more info on auto mount, peep [the Automount FAQ](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Automount.html)

Comment: This sort of works, but doesn't actually solve my problem. If I manually start or restart the autofs service then `ls` the directory, it works fine. But if autofs is started during system boot, then `ls` just shows me an empty directory. If I restart autofs then it works.

I suspect it's due to autofs starting before the SMB shares are mounted, which would bring me back to my original question: How to ensure something doesn't happen until after a certain filesystem has been mounted.

Comment: I think you might not have the right plan of attack here - you take the SMB stuff out of stab and configure auto mount to handle mounting/unmounting it.. That way it'll always be mounted when you want it, and not before.